# Any patch request to Google Groupssettings API gives an error 503

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Since a few days back, we keep getting this error when trying any patch request to the Groupssettings API. It happens every time, and not sporadically which would often be the case with backend errors. Are there issues with the API? It worked before the weekend, and has done for some time before this... I get the same result through our code and through the "Try it now!" on the developer reference page: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups/patch#try-it

`{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "A system error has occurred"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "A system error has occurred"
 }
}`

Comment: Have you tried using an exponential backoff algorithm? As the [document](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/limits) suggested : "For all errors that are time based (maximum of N things for X seconds per thread), especially the 503 status code errors, wait for a small delay before retrying the failed call."

Comment: As I stated, it happens every time, not just sometimes. Google has confirmed that they have reproduced the issue, and they are looking into it. Still awaiting further response. But yes, I do have exponential back-off for everything Google API related.